# How to call TortoiseGit Sync Dialog from command line?

Tags: tortoisegit

I'm trying to to create a batch file that will show TortoiseGit Sync Dialogue (the right click "Git sync..." shell option) for particular repository and I can't find how.
I know how to call TortoiseProc for log commit etc. but there is nothing for Sync Dialogue.

Do you guys know a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe" /command:sync
```

Comment: Thanks! I should of guess it :)

Comment: Is there any command to open the dialog and immediately run the pull command?